# How to only allow syntax in text box with equal sign

Tags: javascript, validation, knockout.js

I wanted to only allow the user to be able to press the submit button if the text in the box has syntax like: City=Detroit

I know that to do this according to text length greater than 0 would work like:

```
<button type="submit" data-bind="enable: itemToAdd().length > 0">Add</button>
```

But how would I only allow the user to submit if the text is like %=%  ?

Thanks

Comment: What library are you using to manage your binding?

Comment: Are you using knockout ?

Comment: yes I'm using knockout, working from this example: http://knockoutjs.com/examples/betterList.html

Comment: Is it possible to answer my original question and ignore the knockout details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may achieve the following behavior by using regular expression matching as shown as below:

```
<button type="submit" data-bind="enable: /^\w+=\w+$/.test(itemToAdd())">Add</button>
```

Please refer to the jsfiddle for working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/zeskysee/umrdz96k/

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Is it possible to achieve this without a library (other than jQuery)? For example can I include it with this code: '<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="javascript:addNewItem()" />'

Comment: So you mean you want to achieve this without using knockout? Just use pure javascript?

Comment: Yes without knockout, just pure JS

Comment: If you want to achieve this without library, you may use the onKeyUp event. During onKeyUp you will validate the input value and enable and disable the button accordingly. Example fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zeskysee/afquzath/2/